# Website safe ruby script execution by user

Tags: ruby, rvm, interpreter

suppose that i want to provide user possibility to put code into textarea and execute it for education purposes.

for example user fills input with `print "hello"`

he submits form -> code is processed by server -> user sees result

but i want to avoid such things as:

- manipulating file system
- dos attack like forks
- doing requests on web
- ...

so this ruby interpreter should be limited only to some basic functions.

is it possible?

Comment: As noted in the linked question/answer, the way to do this in Ruby is by creating an object with only safe methods and running user commands in the context of that object.

Comment: yes, you're right that will be a dup, thanks. closing question

Comment: oh, not exactly - you can call fe: sleep(10)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use JRuby (http://jruby.org/) implementation. You can create sandbox by using JVM security policy features. In such case you don't need to worry about user input - script that is being executed by JRuby will be limited by security settings.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know about limits of interpreter, but I think you need parse input before submitting it and if you have something like `system("rm -rf ~")` don't send it to interpreter and redirecting with warning.